# Get chrome's total memory usage

Tags: memory, chrome, process-management, multithreading

Since google chrome/chromium spawn multiple processes it's harder to see how much total memory these processes use in total.

Is there an easy way to see how much total memory a series of connected processes is using?

Comment: If I convert the numbers that prints out from KiB to GiB then even for Res. Memory I get more than the machine's amount of RAM plus swap. So it seems like something is getting over-counted.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Given that [google killed chrome://memory](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=588790) in March 2016, I am now using [smem](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/smem.8.html):

```
# detailed output, in kB apparently
smem -t -P chrom
# just the total PSS, with automatic unit:
smem -t -k -c pss -P chrom | tail -n 1
```

- to be more accurate replace `chrom` by full path e.g. `/opt/google/chrome` or `/usr/lib64/chromium-browser`
- this works the same for multiprocess firefox (e10s) with `-P firefox`
- be careful, smem reports itself in the output, an additional ~10-20M on my system.
- unlike top it needs root access to accurately monitor root processes -- use `sudo smem` for that.
- see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13754307/2017781) for more details on why smem is a good tool and how to read the output.

Comment: I am not sure that this is working for me.  When I run the second command, I get a returned value of `338.0M`.  This is too low.  When I run System Monitor, I can see that there are 11 chrome processes and each is taking between 70MB and 400MB of RAM.  Not sure if System Monitor is reporting incorrectly or not.

Comment: Same problem for smem on a Kali Linux  2017.1 distribution, the output is 800Mo of ram used by chrome with 5 instances and at least 30 tabs ... And the system monitor does not agree with smem either. Has anyone found a solution to this ? (Thanks for the answer and the references)

Comment: Your  comments deserve a separate question (with full output of conflicting programs). Just post the link in the comment.

Comment: I would use `chrome` instead of just `chorm` because if you are running both chrome and chromium, you 'd be seeing total for both.

Comment: Is there any similar solution on Mac?

Comment: You can exclude `smem` from its own output by using something like `[c]hrome`, e.g. `smem -tkP '[c]hrome'`. This works by matching the `c` inside the square brackets and not the brackets themselves.

Comment: On xfce Mint 19, chromium-browser is located in `/usr/lib/chromium-browser/` for 64bit

Comment: If you would like to show memory usage percentage `%` you can use 
`smem -t -p -c pss -P chrom | tail -n 1`

Comment: 50MB for installing `smem` g** damn, but it works, I really like the second one, that should be the fist TL;DR thing in this answer x)

Answer (score 4):

Improving solution of @eddygeek:

```
smem -ktP chrome
```

Take a look on the value of column "USS", on last line

Note: you can also create an alias for this:

```
alias mem='smem -ktP '
```

And then use:

```
mem chrome
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure that it's not the best solution, still it works for me:

```
#!/bin/sh
ps aux | grep "[/]opt/google/chrome/chrome" | awk '{print $5}' | awk '{sum += $1 } END { print sum }' 
ps aux | grep "[/]opt/google/chrome/chrome" | awk '{print $6}' | awk '{sum += $1 } END { print sum }'
```

Note: change the `[/]opt/google/chrome/chrome` to something appropriate for your system, e.g. if you're on Mac OS X (simply `grep "chrome"` will work).

Comment: This “works” in that it prints a number. However this number is not all that useful since memory that is shared between several processes is counted multiple times.

Comment: I imagine in reality it's still good enough because Chrome is by far the biggest memory hog on typical desktops and when you kill chrome processes your system becomes blazing fast.

Comment: Why two `awk` commands? That is, why not just `... | awk '{sum += $6} END {print sum}'`?

Comment: FWIW, here's a shorter, clearer version: `ps aux | grep "/opt/google/chrome/chrome" | awk '{vsz += $5; rss += $6} END { print "vsz="vsz, "rss="rss }'`

Comment: Note that the square brackets in the `grep` command are supposed to avoid matching the pipeline itself.

Comment: @wjandrea I'm having trouble making that work as an alias or bash function, like so: `alias chromemem="ps aux | grep -i \"chrome\" | awk '{vsz += $5; rss += $6} END { print \"vsz=\"vsz, \"rss=\"rss }'"`

Comment: @Rushi Don't bother. This solution doesn't give a meaningful number. Use `smem` per the top answer. Though FWIW, I would implement it as a script or function, since it's too complex for an alias.

Comment: Is this a number of _bytes_ ? It would be useful to add this info on the answer to save researching time fo the users who want to try this approach.

Comment: For example, if this is a number of bytes, I would add the following extra pipe at the end: `| numfmt --to iec --format "%8.2f"`

Answer (score 2):

Running this:

```
perl -e '$a="x"x1000000000;sleep(10);print"done\n"'
```

takes up 1.8GB RAM. So you would expect running this:

```
perl -e '$a="x"x1000000000;fork;fork;fork;fork;sleep(10);print"done\n"'
```

would take up 16 times as much. But it does not.

This is due to the Linux kernel's intelligent copy-on-write: Because the contents of '$a' does not change, then the memory of '$a' can be shared. But it will only remain shared until '$a' is changed. When that happens, the changed section will be copied and start to take up RAM.

Whether you can measure how much memory is copy-on-write over-committed I do not know. But at least this explains your over-counting.

Answer (score 1):

Just quickly calculate the sum of the processes.

On **Mac**:

- go to `chrome://system/` and select all reported in *mem_usage*
- paste in **SublimeText**
- SelectAll (CMD+'A') and SelectAllLines (CMD+SHIFT+'L')
- CMD+Right (go to eol), Backspace, Backspace, Backspace, ALT+Left, CMD+Backspace
- Backspace, type '+', CMD+'A', CMD+'C'
- open **Terminal**, run `python`, CMD+V, Enter

Et voila! "Easy"...

PS - Shortcut ninjas & 80s/90s Fighting-game players should have no problem with this solution

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution with vim and awk. Open chrome://system, expand mem_usage, copy to vim and execute the regexp:

```
:%s/\D*\(\d*\).MB.*/\1
```

This leaves only the numbers before MB. Save the file and execute

```
cat file | awk '{sum += $1} END {print sum}'
```

I could not convert the vim regexp code to sed.

Answer (score 0):

There is **USS** which is available cross platforms

> The USS (Unique Set Size) is the memory which is unique to a process and which would be freed if the process was terminated right now.

[psutil>4.0 Python library can access it](http://www.pybloggers.com/2016/02/psutil-4-0-0-and-how-to-get-real-process-memory-and-environ-in-python/)

Here is I would use it

```
sudo python3 -c "import psutil;print(sum(p.memory_full_info().uss for p in psutil.Process(pid=292).children())/1024/1024);"
```

where pid=292 is PID of most outer process from Activity Monitor

Answer (score -1):

I knew that chrome/chromium had a task manager, but it doesn't give the total memory used. It turns out that the "Stats for nerds" link in the task manager leads to chrome://memory-redirect/ which does list the total memory used. It would be nice to have external validation of these numbers, as well as a way to get the information on the command line so more could be done with it, but this seems to be the best way available.

Comment: This answer is not valid anymore. See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=588790